# Getting segfault due to string data type variable in PROTOBUF server and client communication through sockets on recv end in c

Tags: c, protobuf-c

I'm new in protobuf

When I am sending a protobuf variable through socket communication on recv end I am trying to display the string variable of protobuf I got segmentation in this remaining Data type other than String they are working fine but string variable case I got segmentation How can I over come in Protobuf string datatype segmentation fault other than we have any other data type for store the string data type.

I create a proto_socket.proto with in string variable name is there I am compile proto_socket.proto with protoc compiler (`protoc proto_socket.proto --c_out <path>`) it create two files two files `proto_socket.pb-c.h`, `proto_socket.pb-c.c`. By using these files I create a `proto_server.c` and `proto_client.c`. And compile it. but at the time of both programms runing I sent a protobuf variable on recv side it give segmentation fault due to trying to display string variable.

**proto_socket.proto**

```
syntax="proto2";
message messages{
   optional int32 age=1;
   optional int32 year=2;
   optional string name=3;
}
```

**generated structure for the .proto**

```
struct  _Messages
{
   ProtobufCMessage base;
   protobuf_c_boolean has_age;
   int32_t age;
   protobuf_c_boolean has_year;
   int32_t year;
   char *name;
};
```

**proto_client.c**

```
 void *clientThread(void *arg)
 {
   Messages t_message;
  //while(1)
  {
  int32_t s32_send_status;
  t_message.age =70;
  t_message.year=2018;
  t_message.name="anu";

    s32_send_status=send(gs32_clientSocket ,(unsigned char *)
            (&t_message),sizeof(t_message) ,0);
    if(s32_send_status>0){
        printf("data send to server.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("failed to send data to server\n");
    }
    /*gs32_valread=read( gs32_clientSocket , gars32_buffer , 1024);
    if(gs32_valread==0){
        printf("connection loss\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(gs32_valread<0){
        printf("error:read\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        printf("server replay:%s\n",gars32_buffer);
    }*/
}
sleep(2);
return NULL;
}
```

**proto_server.c**

```
void *socketThread(void *arg)
{

Messages t_message;

//while(1)
{
    gs32_valread = read( gs32_new_socket,(unsigned char *)
            (&t_message), 1024);
    if(gs32_valread==0){
         printf("disconnected\n");
         exit(1);
    }
    else if(gs32_valread<0){
         printf("error\n");
         exit(1);
    }
    else{
        printf("age=%d\n",t_message.age );
        printf("year=%d\n",t_message.year);
        gs32_birth_year=(t_message.year)-(t_message.age);
        printf("birth year=%d\n",gs32_birth_year);
        printf("name=%s\n",t_message.name);
    }
    sleep(1);
    close(gs32_new_socket);
}
return NULL;
}
```

and the result,

```
age=70
year=2018
birth year=1948
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: What is `t_message.name` actually defined as?

Comment: It looks as though you could be sending a pointer (because of `t_message.name="anu";`) which won't make any sense to the recipient.

Comment: 'printf("server replay:%s\n",gars32_buffer);'  it's not clear that 'gars32_buffer' is guaranteed NUL_terminated.

Comment: Isn't the *type* for `optional string name=3;` supposed to be `2` not `3`? From looking [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) at the message types along with an example to encode `"testing"`.